# Using automapper expression mapping of id class to string lead to translation error in EFCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mapping, expression, automapper

I use AutoMapper to translate between business logic objects (Blo) and data transfer objects (Dto). The blo-class contain an id that is a class wheras the dto contains a string for that id. To load objects out of a database an expression on blo-level is created and translated via AutoMapper to dto-level.

The classes are:

```
public class Blo
{
    public Blo(BloId id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public BloId Id { get; set; }
}

[Table("dtos")]
public class Dto
{
    [Column("id")]
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class BloId
{
    private readonly string _value;

    public BloId(string value = null)
    {
        this._value = value ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(BloId left, BloId right)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, right))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (left is null || right is null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return left._value == right._value;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(BloId left, BloId right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this._value;
    }
}
```

These classes are very simplyfied and all the unneeded code is omitted due to focus on the real problem.

The mapping I created is straight forward (using the hints of [that github issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping/issues/18)):

```
cfg.CreateMap<Blo, Dto>(MemberList.None)
    .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id.ToString() == dst.Id)
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id.ToString()));
cfg.CreateMap<Dto, Blo>(MemberList.None)
    .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id.ToString())
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new BloId(src.Id)));
```

I created a `DbContext` from EFCore and the following code to find an item:

```
var mapper = CreateMapper();
await using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var idToFind = new BloId("Container-Id 000");

    Expression<Func<Blo, bool>> bloFilter = c => c.Id == idToFind;
    var dtoFilter = mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<Dto, bool>>>(bloFilter);
    var found = await ctx.Dtos.FirstOrDefaultAsync(dtoFilter);
}
```

This works as expected if I use an in-memory database.
But if I switch to e.g. a SQLite database the following exception occurs:

`The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Dto> .Where(d => new BloId(d.Id) == Container-Id 000)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.`

And the reason is absolutally clear:
The `bloFilter` is

```
c => (c.Id == value(AutoMapperVsEfCore.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).idToFind)
```

that is translated to the `dtoFilter`

```
c => (new BloId(c.Id) == Container-Id 000)
```

***That is the problem!*** There is no way to create an instance of `BloId` in SQL.

The expected dto-filter might be something like: `c => (c.Id == "Container-Id 000")`

But I've absolutally no idea how I have to configure AutoMapper to translate my specified blo-filter to a working dto-filter.

How do I create such a filter?

*What I've tried so far*

- Changing the blo-filter to `c => c.Id.ToString() == idToFind.ToString()` but this results in an dto-filter of `c => (new BloId(c.Id).ToString() == Container-Id 000.ToString())` having the same problem.
- Changing the mapping for id to

  ```
  cfg.CreateMap<BloId, string>(MemberList.None).ConvertUsing(id => id.ToString());
  cfg.CreateMap<string, BloId>(MemberList.None).ConvertUsing(id => new BloId(id));

   cfg.CreateMap<Blo, Dto>(MemberList.None)
       .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id.ToString() == dst.Id)
       .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
   cfg.CreateMap<Dto, Blo>(MemberList.None)
       .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id.ToString())
       .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
  ```

  but this results in an exception during expression mapping because of incompatible types.

For completeness the used `DbContext` is:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public const string DatabasePath = @"D:\Temp\testing.db";

    public DbSet<Dto> Dtos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        //optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("testing");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = DatabasePath }.ToString());

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Content of CreateMapper:

```
private static IMapper CreateMapper()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(
        cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Blo, Dto>(MemberList.None)
                .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id.ToString() == dst.Id)
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id.ToString()));
            cfg.CreateMap<Dto, Blo>(MemberList.None)
                .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id.ToString())
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new BloId(src.Id)));
        });
    var result = config.CreateMapper();
    result.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you show `CreateMapper`?

Comment: @Vernou I added the content of `CreateMapper`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and countless tests I found a working solution.

I use a seperate property for querying the business logik elements:

```
public class Blo
{
    public Blo(BloId id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public BloId Id { get; }

    public string QueryId => this.Id.ToString();
}
```

The data transfer object is unchanged. The mapping is now:

```
cfg.CreateMap<BloId, string>(MemberList.None).ConvertUsing(id => id.ToString());
cfg.CreateMap<string, BloId>(MemberList.None).ConvertUsing(value => new BloId(value));

cfg.CreateMap<Dto, Blo>(MemberList.None)
    .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.QueryId)
    .ForCtorParam("id", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.QueryId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
cfg.CreateMap<Blo, Dto>(MemberList.None)
    .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.QueryId == dst.Id)
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.QueryId))
    .ForSourceMember(src => src.Id, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());
```

The used `DbContext` is still the same.

**old query**

```
c => c.Id == idToFind
```

**new query**

```
c => c.QueryId == idToFind.ToString()
```

This approach does also work for find an item in an array like:

```
c => new[] { idToFind.ToString() }.Contains(c.QueryId)
```

Until I'll find a better solution this will be the way to go for me.

Comment: I don't know about the rest, but the `ConvertUsing` stuff was obvious, as per my initial comment.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu What _initial comment_ do you mean? My sample in question doesn't need a `ConvertUsing` for id. It is now needed because ctor-mapping that maps from `string` to `BloId`. The main change in that solution is that I use `QueryId` in blo-filter instead of `Id`.

Comment: You've asked this question before and it was obvious that `ConvertUsing` was needed. But you chose a different approach :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu The previously asked question was about a mapping problem. The expression mapping was not working but the problem was a missing property mapping. I only added a ctor mapping that worked fine for persisting the objects but a query does not create an instance - it only accesses the members. This problem is new because the expression mapping works but creates an result that is not usable in SQL because of the blo object creation.

Comment: Given your previous mapping, the result made sense. All I'm saying is that the new mapping makes a lot more sense. And that was easy to see.